How to convert a string to a sequence of integers corresponding to the Unicode code points, and vice versa?
Suppose that I have a file (in UTF-8) that contains a line like this:
≈+

There are five characters in this line:

U+1D465: MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL X;
U+2248: ALMOST EQUAL TO;
U+1D45A: MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL M;
U+002B: PLUS SIGN;
U+1D45B: MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL N.

Does gawk allow to convert this line to a sequence of integers (in a decimal base) corresponding to five Unicode code points — that is, 119909, 8776, 119898, 43, 119899? If yes, how to do this? And vice versa, given a string like 119909, 8776, 119898, 43, 119899, how to interpret it as a sequence of Unicode code points (in a decimal base) and convert to the sequence of corresponding characters (≈+)?
EDIT
Reformulating the first problem: is gawk able to output the binary representation of a given string? For example, consider the string á à. Its UTF-8 encoding is 0xc3 0xa1 0x20 0xc3 0xa0. Is it possible to convert this three-character string to a sequence of five numbers (in the range of 0-255) that correspond to five bytes?

Weirdly, the plus sign I copy/pasted out of your question is U+DF2B. Maybe it's something my IOS phone did.

From the manual: There is no standard, built-in way to distinguish characters from bytes in an awk program. For an awk implementation of wc, which needs to make such a distinction, we will have to use an external extension.

your "reformulation" is actually a very different question. For example, the codepoint for á does not directly contain either 0xc3 or 0xa1; it is U+00E1 (=225)

@jhnc: <your "reformulation" is actually a very different question> — my formulations (of the first problem) are equivalent in the sense that given either one of representations (a single integer corresponding to a code point, or a sequence of byte values), it would not be too hard to obtain the other. For example, given 0xc3, 0xa1, we need to detect that 0xa1 is the end of a boundary for a character, then (according to the UTF-8 encoding algorithm) extract the required bits from two bytes, then collect these bits into a single value.

Using the encoding table from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
and not aiming for any kind of efficiency, nor avoidance of redundant code, nor doing any checks that the input is valid UTF-8:
LC_ALL=C gawk '
   BEGIN { for(i=0;i<256;++i) ord[sprintf("%c",i)]=i }
   {
      n=split($0,a,//)
      for(i=1;i<=n;){

         A =           ord[ b1=a[i++] ]
         B = (A>191) ? ord[ b2=a[i++] ] : 0
         C = (A>223) ? ord[ b3=a[i++] ] : 0
         D = (A>239) ? ord[ b4=a[i++] ] : 0

         if (D) {
            A10 = A%4
            A2 = (int(A/4))%2
            B3210 = B%16
            B54 = (int(B/16))%4
            C10 = C%4
            C5432 = (int(C/4))%16
            D3210 = D%16
            D54 = (int(D/16))%4
            cpint = (1048576*A2) + (65536*((4*A10)+B54)) + (4096*B3210) + (256*C5432) + (16*((4*C10)+D54)) + (D3210)
            bytes = b1 b2 b3 b4
            bytehex = sprintf("0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x", A,B,C,D)

         } else if (C) {
            A3210 = A%16
            B10 = B%4
            B5432 = (int(B/4))%16
            C3210 = C%16
            C54 = (int(C/16))%4
            cpint = (4096*A3210) + (256*B5432) + (16*((4*B10)+C54)) + (C3210)
            bytes = b1 b2 b3
            bytehex = sprintf("0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x", A,B,C)

         } else if (B) {
            A10 = A%4
            A432 = (int(A/4))%8
            B3210 = B%16
            B54 = (int(B/16))%4
            cpint = (256*A432) + (16*((4*A10)+B54)) + (B3210)
            bytes = b1 b2
            bytehex = sprintf("0x%02x 0x%02x", A,B)

         } else {
            cpint = A
            bytes = b1
            bytehex = sprintf("0x%02x", A)
         }
     
         printf "%s\t= U+%04X\t= %-12d: %s\n", bytes, cpint, cpint, bytehex
      }
      print "--------"
   }
' file.txt

Running on input:
á à
GBP £10
≈+
푥≈푚+푛
‍️

¯\_(ツ)_/¯
الكل في المجمو عة (5)

gives:
á       = U+00E1    = 225         : 0xc3 0xa1
        = U+0020    = 32          : 0x20
à       = U+00E0    = 224         : 0xc3 0xa0
--------
G       = U+0047    = 71          : 0x47
B       = U+0042    = 66          : 0x42
P       = U+0050    = 80          : 0x50
        = U+0020    = 32          : 0x20
£       = U+00A3    = 163         : 0xc2 0xa3
1       = U+0031    = 49          : 0x31
0       = U+0030    = 48          : 0x30
--------
      = U+1D465   = 119909      : 0xf0 0x9d 0x91 0xa5
≈       = U+2248    = 8776        : 0xe2 0x89 0x88
      = U+1D45A   = 119898      : 0xf0 0x9d 0x91 0x9a
+       = U+002B    = 43          : 0x2b
      = U+1D45B   = 119899      : 0xf0 0x9d 0x91 0x9b
--------
푥       = U+D465    = 54373       : 0xed 0x91 0xa5
≈       = U+2248    = 8776        : 0xe2 0x89 0x88
푚       = U+D45A    = 54362       : 0xed 0x91 0x9a
+       = U+002B    = 43          : 0x2b
푛       = U+D45B    = 54363       : 0xed 0x91 0x9b
--------
      = U+1F636   = 128566      : 0xf0 0x9f 0x98 0xb6
‍       = U+200D    = 8205        : 0xe2 0x80 0x8d
      = U+1F32B   = 127787      : 0xf0 0x9f 0x8c 0xab
️       = U+FE0F    = 65039       : 0xef 0xb8 0x8f
--------
      = U+1F1EC   = 127468      : 0xf0 0x9f 0x87 0xac
      = U+1F1E7   = 127463      : 0xf0 0x9f 0x87 0xa7
--------
¯       = U+00AF    = 175         : 0xc2 0xaf
\       = U+005C    = 92          : 0x5c
_       = U+005F    = 95          : 0x5f
(       = U+0028    = 40          : 0x28
ツ       = U+30C4    = 12484       : 0xe3 0x83 0x84
)       = U+0029    = 41          : 0x29
_       = U+005F    = 95          : 0x5f
/       = U+002F    = 47          : 0x2f
¯       = U+00AF    = 175         : 0xc2 0xaf
--------
ا       = U+0627    = 1575        : 0xd8 0xa7
ل       = U+0644    = 1604        : 0xd9 0x84
ك       = U+0643    = 1603        : 0xd9 0x83
ل       = U+0644    = 1604        : 0xd9 0x84
        = U+0020    = 32          : 0x20
ف       = U+0641    = 1601        : 0xd9 0x81
ي       = U+064A    = 1610        : 0xd9 0x8a
        = U+0020    = 32          : 0x20
ا       = U+0627    = 1575        : 0xd8 0xa7
ل       = U+0644    = 1604        : 0xd9 0x84
م       = U+0645    = 1605        : 0xd9 0x85
ج       = U+062C    = 1580        : 0xd8 0xac
م       = U+0645    = 1605        : 0xd9 0x85
و       = U+0648    = 1608        : 0xd9 0x88
        = U+0020    = 32          : 0x20
ع       = U+0639    = 1593        : 0xd8 0xb9
ة       = U+0629    = 1577        : 0xd8 0xa9
        = U+0020    = 32          : 0x20
(       = U+0028    = 40          : 0x28
5       = U+0035    = 53          : 0x35
)       = U+0029    = 41          : 0x29
--------


reversing the process (converting codepoints into byte sequences) is left as an exercise for the reader ...

I get different results for all characters whose code point is greater than 0xFFFF. For example, I have got = U+D835 = 55349 : 0xed 0xa0 0xb5 followed by = U+DC65 = 56421 : 0xed 0xb1 0xa5 (instead of the correct = U+1D465 = 119909 : 0xf0 0x9d 0x91 0xa5) for . I will test in a different environment later, then report.

setting LC_ALL=C instead of LANG=C makes the cygwin gawk I have here do what is wanted

How does %s work in this code? It was used to print a single character at the beginning of each line? It is not %c, it is %s. Why does it print a single character?

The intent is to print bytes which is the string containing the bytes we believe make up each UTF-8 character (some or all of b1,b2,b3,b4). Because of LC_ALL=C awk thinks it is printing a string of 1-byte characters but the terminal (or wherever the output ends up) will treat each sequence as a single UTF-8 character.

It seems that I have found why the code outputs the UTF-16 encoding for some characters. It is probably because even though file -bi input.txt shows text/plain; charset=utf-8, I have the UTF-16 encoded characters in the input (which was found from the output of the xxd command). I have no idea why files can be encoded like that. When I use the code for properly encoded UTF-8, it outputs the correct results.

@jhnc in my cygwin environment LC_CTYPE is set by default to en_US.UTF-8, so setting LANG to C would have no effect since cygwin examines LC_ALL then LC_CTYPE then LANG in order, see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-locale.html. If you have the same situation that'd explain why setting LANG didn't work for you but setting LC_ALL did. You could alternatively call gawk with the -b option to tell it to use bytes.

@EdMorton thanks. if I'd known about gawk's -b option, that would have been easier! (I actually only used gawk specifically because of the split on empty string (but if replaced with substr, all my normal awk implementations seem to do what's wanted). I haven't used cygwin before (nor win11, but was a good opportunity to try out dockur/windows under ubuntu), so useful to know about the environment defaults

@EdMorton now that I actually read the purpose of LC_CTYPE, I should definitely have been using it instead of LANG

To be honest, I don't think I've ever had reason to set any locale variable except for LC_ALL.

@EdMorton yeah, on my systems, I only haveLC_COLLATE=C (I prefer it for ls and sort order). Everything else is unset and defaults to C.UTF8 so I'd completely forgotten about the precedence of LANG

Impressive in awk! At least for me, the Tamil string "நகரத்தில்" is not correctly handled as graphemes. Rather, that is treated as single bytes. (Tamil is the goto language to break UTF-8 parsing btw, or arabic as you have demonstrated...)

@dawg thanks. the code only aims to parse out the codepoints from the bytestream. doing anything clever like grouping is way above my paygrade. :-) (and wasn't part of the question)

@jhnc: That was more of a note to future readers (use a proper tool kinda note) vs anything that you should/could attempt to fix. This awk is like watching someone spin plates on the end of a stick -- impressive but hard to eat dinner that way... ;-)

You didn't specify, but with Unicode you should be concerned with graphemes vs single characters. The character ä can either be a single code point or be a grapheme cluster composed of the letter a followed by the combining DIAERESIS character.
The easiest command line tools for unicode for me are either Ruby or Perl.
Given:
$ s='≈+'

With Ruby you can trivially get your output like so:
$ ruby -lne 'puts $_.each_grapheme_cluster.map{|g| "%4.4x" % g.ord}.join(", ")' <<< "$s"
1d465, 2248, 1d45a, 002b, 1d45b

You can also get fancier by using a common gem for code point names:
$ ruby -r"uniscribe/kernel_method" -lne 'uniscribe $_' <<< "$s"
  1D465 ├─        ├─ MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL X
   2248 ├─ ≈        ├─ ALMOST EQUAL TO
  1D45A ├─        ├─ MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL M
   002B ├─ +        ├─ PLUS SIGN
  1D45B ├─        ├─ MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL N

Where the focus on graphemes becomes more important is when a language is non Latin and many or most of the characters are composed.
Consider this Tamil string where most of the graphemes are composed from one or more characters:
$ s="நகரத்தில்"
$ ruby -r"uniscribe/kernel_method" -lne 'uniscribe $_' <<< "$s"
   0BA8 ├─ ந        ├─ TAMIL LETTER NA
   0B95 ├─ க        ├─ TAMIL LETTER KA
   0BB0 ├─ ர        ├─ TAMIL LETTER RA
   ---- ├┬ த்       ├┬ Composition: TAMIL CONSONANT T
   0BA4 │├─ த       │├─ TAMIL LETTER TA
   0BCD │└─ ◌்      │└─ TAMIL SIGN VIRAMA
   ---- ├┬ தி       ├┬ Composition: TAMIL SYLLABLE TI
   0BA4 │├─ த       │├─ TAMIL LETTER TA
   0BBF │└─ ி       │└─ TAMIL VOWEL SIGN I
   ---- ├┬ ல்       ├┬ Composition: TAMIL CONSONANT L
   0BB2 │├─ ல       │├─ TAMIL LETTER LA
   0BCD │└─ ◌்      │└─ TAMIL SIGN VIRAMA

You can see it is more complex than most approaches here including my first script. While $_.each_grapheme_cluster.map{|g| "%4.4x" % g.ord} correctly identifies each code point, it does not identify the compositional relationships or grapheme boundaries.
My first script can then be rewritten to handle grapheme clusters such as in the Tamil example:
ruby -lne 'puts $_.each_grapheme_cluster.map{|g| 
    cluster=g.unicode_normalize(:nfd).chars    # all bytes of the grapheme
    if cluster.size==1                         # single byte?
        "\"#{g}\": #{"%4.4x" % g.ord}"
    elsif cluster.size>1                       # multibyte
        "\"#{g}\" => " + cluster.
            map{|c| "\"#{c}\": #{"%4.4x" % c.ord}"}.join(" + ")
    end
}' <<< "$s"

Prints:
"ந": 0ba8
"க": 0b95
"ர": 0bb0
"த்" => "த": 0ba4 + "்": 0bcd
"தி" => "த": 0ba4 + "ி": 0bbf
"ல்" => "ல": 0bb2 + "்": 0bcd

And running on this example file (thanks jhnc):
á à
GBP £10
≈+
푥≈푚+푛
‍️

¯\_(ツ)_/¯
الكل في المجمو عة (5)

ruby -lne 'puts $_.each_grapheme_cluster.map{|g| 
    cluster=g.unicode_normalize(:nfd).chars    # all bytes of the grapheme
    if cluster.size==1                         # single byte?
        "\"#{g}\": #{"%4.4x" % g.ord}"
    elsif cluster.size>1                       # multibyte
        "\"#{g}\" => " + cluster.
            map{|c| "\"#{c}\": #{"%4.4x" % c.ord}"}.join(" + ")
    end
}' jhnc.txt

Prints:
"á" => "a": 0061 + "́": 0301
" ": 0020
"à" => "a": 0061 + "̀": 0300
"G": 0047
"B": 0042
"P": 0050
" ": 0020
"£": 00a3
"1": 0031
"0": 0030
"": 1d465
"≈": 2248
"": 1d45a
"+": 002b
"": 1d45b
"푥" => "ᄑ": 1111 + "ᅭ": 116d + "ᆰ": 11b0
"≈": 2248
"푚" => "ᄑ": 1111 + "ᅬ": 116c + "ᇁ": 11c1
"+": 002b
"푛" => "ᄑ": 1111 + "ᅬ": 116c + "ᇂ": 11c2
"‍️" => "": 1f636 + "‍": 200d + "": 1f32b + "️": fe0f
"" => "": 1f1ec + "": 1f1e7
"¯": 00af
"\": 005c
"_": 005f
"(": 0028
"ツ": 30c4
")": 0029
"_": 005f
"/": 002f
"¯": 00af
"ا": 0627
"ل": 0644
"ك": 0643
"ل": 0644
" ": 0020
"ف": 0641
"ي": 064a
" ": 0020
"ا": 0627
"ل": 0644
"م": 0645
"ج": 062c
"م": 0645
"و": 0648
" ": 0020
"ع": 0639
"ة": 0629
" ": 0020
"(": 0028
"5": 0035
")": 0029


shouldn't you be normalizing to NFC instead of NFD ?

as for the hangul decompositions, every combo officially used in the korean language today (19 x 21  x 28 => 11,172 syllables) have their own code point in composed form (specifically, U+AC00…U+D7A3), so one shouldn't be decomposing them anymore other than for info purposes. On the other hand, even though there are fewer than 300 national flags I still don't believe Unicode Consortium has forced allocated code points for them other than using those "regional indicator" pairs.


given a string like 119909, 8776, 119898, 43, 119899, how to interpret
it as a sequence of Unicode code points (in a decimal base) and
convert to the sequence of corresponding characters (≈+)?

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
119909, 8776, 119898, 43, 119899

then
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]+"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){printf "%c",$i};printf "\n"}' file.txt

gives output
≈+

Explanation: I summon GNU AWK with en_US.UTF-8 interpretation of byte sequences as characters, I inform GNU AWK that field is one-or-more digits. I use for loop to iterate over fields and use printf with %c to convert code to character. After fields are processed I add newline using printf.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

I tested in Cygwin; it prints 푥≈푚+푛.

@lyricallywicked I never used Cygwin I can only suggest to summon convent of Cygwin of Cygwin ninjas and ask them

I doubt that in this case, Cygwin is the cause of the problem. If the string is, say, á à, its binary representation (assuming UTF-8) is 0xc3 0xa1 0x20 0xc3 0xa0, regardless of whether I am reading it in Cygwin or not. All I want is to print the values of these bytes...

@lyricallywicked I tested my solution at ideone.com and got desired result (without setting LC_CTYPE as there is not way to do so as far as I know) and got ≈+ as desired

looks like: https://youtu.be/4mRxIgu9R70?t=1634 ("there's chinese in the event logs" - in your case korean?)

@lyricallywicked see edit to my answer - this output is getting mangled on your system

There's no need to premake any UTF-8 customized ord[] arrays/tables - just one for unsigned byte ordinals [0 - 255] suffices, because the multi-byte UTF-8 encodings are all related by this formula :


a is always the leading byte in the formulas,



 64*(-2+64*(-2+64*(-2-16*(16-2^(4-4))+a)+b)+c)+d
 64*(-2+64*(       -2-16*(16-2^(4-3))+a)+b)+c
 64*(              -2-16*(16-2^(4-2))+a)+b


 64 ( 64 ( 64 ( a - 240 - 2 ) - 2 + b ) - 2 + c ) + d
      64 ( 64 ( a - 224 - 2 ) - 2 + b )     + c
           64 ( a - 192 - 2 )     + b

            b + ( a - 192 - 2 )                       * 64
      c + ( b + ( a - 224 - 2 )            * 64 - 2 ) * 64
d + ( c + ( b + ( a - 240 - 2 ) * 64 - 2 ) * 64 - 2 ) * 64


Via these formulas, one can go from UTF-8 back to code point using nothing but unsigned byte ordinals, and never once even having to do division, modulo, or bit-masking operation(s) at all.

The -2 at each layer is to remove 0x80 from each of the trailing bytes.


         241 ::::::: 159 ::::::: 164 ::::: 161
         /           /           /         /
     64 * ( -2 + 64 * ( -2 + 64 * ( -2 - 240 \
     + 241 )   +   159 )   +   164 )   + 161

                     239 ::::::: 163 ::::: 191
                     /           /         /
                 64 * ( -2 + 64 * ( -2 - 224 \
               + 239 )     +   163 )   + 191

                                 217 ::::: 181
                                 /         /
                             64 * ( -2 - 192 \
                             + 217 )   + 181


     64*(-2+64*(-2+64*(-2+16*(2^(4-4)-16)+241)+159)+164)+161
     64*(-2+64*(       -2+16*(2^(4-3)-16)+239)     +163)+191
     64*(              -2+16*(2^(4-2)-16)+217)          +181


So this is what the function looks like implementing this approach (with all the extra code is just for UTF-8 validation) :

    function ordC(__, _, ___, ____, _____) {

        # __| any byte sequence
        #   |
        #   |--> Unicode code point of left-most
        #        UTF8-encoded character, or ordinal-256 of
        #        left-most byte if UTF8-invalid

        if (__ == (_ = ""))

            return ++_ - ((++_ + _^++_)^_) ^ !+FLG_AWK_NAWK

        if (_ = (FLG_GAWK_P6X < FLG_AWK_MAWK) + FLG_AWK_NAWK)

            if (length(__ = substr(__, ___ = _, _ += ++_)) == ___ ||
                                                 "\364\300" <= __ || __ < "\302")
                return byte2sgned[substr(__,___, ___)]
            else
                ___ = split(substr(__, ___, _ - (__ < "\360") \
                                              - (__ < "\340")), ____, _ = "")

        else if ((__ = sprintf("%.*s", ++_, __)) in byte2dec)

            return byte2sgned[__]
        else
            gsub(reFLEX_200277, (_ = " ") ("&")_, __) < (___ = split(__, ____, _))

        if (___ == (_ = !!___))

            return !_ ? _ : byte2sgned[____[_]]
        else
            __ = (_____ = ____[_])____[++_]

        if (_ = FLG_GAWK_P6X < (_ < ___) &&
            (___ < _+_ \
                ? __ < "\340" (_ = "\240") || (__ < "\355" _) < (__ < "\356") \
                : __ < "\360" (_ = "\220") || ("\364" _) <= __))

            return byte2sgned[_____]

        __ = ++_ + ___
        _ *= -++_^(_+_+_)

        while (--__)
            ____[__] = byte2dec[____[__]] + (__ < __*__ ? _ : \
                       ((_ = __ + __)^((_ += _) - ___) - (_ *= _)) * _)

        _ += _ += _
        if (FLG_GAWK_P6X * ((__ += __ ^= __) < ___)  &&
                       _____ ~ "\340|\355|\360|\364" &&
           (____[__] < __^((__ += __) + (___ < __))) == !____[__<_])
                return byte2sgned[_____]

        for (__ in ____)
            if (_ <= (__ = ____[__]) || __ < !_)
                return byte2sgned[_____]

        return \
        ___ == (_ ^= ! (__ = _)) + _ \
                    ?         __*____[_++ ] + ____[_] : \
        ___ < ++_+_ ?     __*(__*____[_<__] + ____[_]) + ____[___] \
                    : __*(__*(__*____[_<__] + ____[_]) + ____[++_]) + ____[___]
    }


This has the potential of being the a really great answer. You just need to add an example?
